# how to calculate the speed of the vehicle using the accelerometer?

Tags: android, accelerometer

actually i have many questions about the accelerometer.

1) using the device accelerometer option,can i calculate the car's speed?

2) Are there any restrictions about the road quality (it should be flat, no bumps) and does the gravity affect on the result?

3) is there any limitation about the API number?

4) from the usability view, is the idea of "telling the user how far is he from a traffic jam (distance) and approximately he could reach this jam in .... minute" logical and do i need in order to apply this idea to be connected and to turn on the GPS to get the current status of the traffic, doesn't that affect on the battery??!

5) trying to get some similar application, could any one help me on that?!!

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to glean distance traveled over time using a motion sensor like the accelerometer.  Instead, you'll need sampled geo coordinates, a method for calculating the distance between the geo coordinates, and the amount of time between the capture of those coordinates to compute a velocity.

Comment: Another thought - I suppose it's possible, although not realistic to calculate velocity as the integral of your acceleration data over time.  I'm not sure how accurate this is going to be since the device will be under the influence of other forces besides that of the motion of the vehicle...

Answer (score 1):

1) this is theoretically posible if to take the differentials of the reading an sum them you will get the speed, but I tried it for one of my projects and I couldn't get it to work. (A friend of mine who did his phd in acceromiters told me It wouldn't)

2) gravity is prety constant acoss the earth

4)GPS chip drains the battery alot and so does network calls, this approach uses both

Comment: ok let me ask in a different way, could i develop an application that calculate the speed of the car using the GPS or the accelerator.. and if yes HOW?? i found nothing..

Comment: got get the speed of the device itis probably best to look at using the gps and a location listener. the during the onlocationchanged method you will get a location object that has speed as a property.